# how to set scrapy shell's default user agent

Tags: command-line, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I set the default user-agent in `settings.py`, but I still had to go to the trouble of adding the `-s` option and the corresponding value to set the user_agent every time I used the `scrapy shell`.

I know I can use commands like `alias scrapys="scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='xxxxx'"` to do it, but is there any better way to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Setting `USER_AGENT` in `settings.py` should suffice your need. If you have problem with this way, please provide more info (like print you project structure with `tree` command.).

To make `settings.py` being read by `scrapy shell ...` command, make sure

1. You're running the command in the project root, where you can see a `scrapy.cfg` file.
2. `settings.py` module path is defined in the `scrapy.cfg`.

   ```
   [settings]
   default = project_name.settings
   ```

   `project_name.settings` is the module path to `settings.py`.

#### Solution 2

Use spider class attribute `Spider.custom_settings`.

```py
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'some value',
    }
```

This spider specific setting dict `.custom_settings` overrule values the global `settings.py`.

#### Ref

- [`settings.py` doc from Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.5/topics/settings.html)

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I didn't run the command in the project root.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Simba's solution 1... I actually added a list of different user agents in settings.py. So my variable looked kinda like this...

```
# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = random.choice(USERAGENTS)
```

This way you can rotate user agents every time you open up your scrapy shell. Just make sure that the list is defined *before* this line of code in settings.py. Also don't forget to `import random` near the top.

Happy scrapy-ing :)